# Eclipse JBoss hot code replace

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 4.2 and JBoss 7.

I have Build automatically checked in Eclipse.

Even then I have to build and redeploy the EAR file to JBOSS to test any code changes I make in Eclipse debug mode.

Am I missing something here?

THanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the "Build automatically" option in eclipse do is that when you modify the source code of a class, this one will be automatically compiled, which doesn't mean that all the whole project that contains the class (i.e. war, jar, ear ...) is redeployed in the server. But of course it helps in the speed of deployment, because the classes you've been modifying are already compiled when you manually build or deploy the project.

On the other hand, to avoid problems with redeployments, you'd better set up JBoss to delete the files related to the application keeps in the work directory, when the application is undeployed / redeployed. Look at [this stackoverflow thread for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370879/jboss-redeploy-changes-on-exploded-deployment-directory/13375281#13375281).

Comment: Great! Thanks Toni. I get the point. So there is no way I can test an application during development / bug fixing without redeployment and restarting of the server?

Comment: You need to redeploy the application, but you shouldn't need to restart the server, if you've hot deployment active in JBoss. Hot deployment is not advised in production environment, but you should be able to redeploy the app without restarting it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with extra information about redeployment.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the "Build automatically" option:

In order for the Deployment Scanner in JBoss to work, you have to have it turned on in JBoss.

Also, you need to add your project to the JBoss server in the Servers window. Look for the "Add or Remove..." option.

Once your project is added, any changes you make to your code will get detected and your module will be redeployed automatically in the background. Failing that and assuming your project doesn't have a snag, you can use mvn install & mvn jboss-as:deploy to manual update your module.

Beware, sometimes mvn doesn't pick up the latest java code. This seems to be a project configuration issue more than anything. Re-creating the project seems to correct the issue.

Also, keep an eye out for duplicate persistence.xml files.

You only need one.